# Modify icon size and color of ion-accordion in Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement a menu using the new [ion-accordion](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/accordion) in Ionic 6.

The documentation says that an `ion-icon` is automatically added when we use `ion-item` in the `header` slot. They have provided a component property to change the icon name or even to use a custom icon (not an `ion-icon`), but the documentation doesn't mention **how to change the default icon's size and color**.

[image]

```
<ion-accordion-group>
 <ion-accordion>
     <ion-item slot="header">
         <ion-label>
             Home
         </ion-label>
     </ion-item>
 </ion-accordion>
</ion-accordion-group>
```

**I have tried:**

```
ion-accordion-group {

  ion-accordion {

    ion-item {

      // Attempt 1
      ion-icon {
        // Note. The default icon has this class
        &.ion-accordion-toggle-icon {
          font-size: 128px !important;
          color: red;
        }
      }

      // Attempt 2
      ion-icon[slot="end"] {
        font-size: 128px;
        color: red;
      }

    }

    // Attempt 3
    ion-item[slot="header"] {
        ion-icon[slot="end"] {
          font-size: 128px;
          color: red;
        }
    }

  }

}
```

I would like to change the size and color of the default icon that `ion-accordion` provides.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this working URL : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-jvsxxr?file=src/styles.css

apply below code in `styles.scss` Or `global.scss` file

```
ion-accordion-group{
    ion-accordion {
        .ion-accordion-toggle-icon {
            font-size: 50px;
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works. My old attempts are also working, the trick is to add the style in `global.scss`. I think the question now is, why in `global.scss`? why is not working if the style is inside a component's style file? Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: The style also works if you use `:host ::ng-deep` inside the component's style file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use scss, you can use this in your style.css:

```
.ion-accordion-toggle-icon{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

It works too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to totally control your component by warpping a div and create your own IonItem:

```
<IonAccordionGroup value="completed">
  <IonAccordion value="completed"> 
    <div slot="header">
       <IonItem button lines="none">
           You can put any icon and anything here
       </IonItem>
    </div>
  </IonAccordion>
</IonAccordionGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution does not work for me (the linked StackBlitz is broken as well).

To solve this, simply insert an `ion-icon` tag with the `ion-accordion-toggle-icon` class inside the `ion-item` which you are using as the accordion header.  This will replace the default icon.  For example:

```
<ion-accordion>
  <ion-item slot="header">
    <ion-label>Section Header</ion-label>
    
    <!-- add the following tag -->
    <ion-icon
      class="ion-accordion-toggle-icon"
      name="logo-ionic"
      slot="end"
      color="white">
    </ion-icon>

  </ion-item>
  ...
</ion-accordion>
```